# mapped data html/thymeleaf form action to spring controller , unable to gets the data spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-thymeleaf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud2GP.png)here is my html/thymeleaf content

```
 <tbody>
    <th:block th:each="map : ${status}">
        <tr th:each="e : ${map}">
            <td th:text="${e.key}"></td>
            <!--<td th:text="${e.value}"></td>-->
            <td th:each="item : ${e.value}">
                <th:block th:text="${item}"/>
            </td>

            <td>



                <form action="update" method="post" th:object="${e}">

                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update" name="${e}"
                           th:field = "${e}" />


                           <!--th:key = "${e.key}"
                           th:values = "${e.value}" -->

                </form>

            </td>

        </tr>
    </th:block>
```

th:object="${e}" or th:field = "${e}" holds the data i.e Project Development Plan=[Proposed, draft]" , see below

and My controller,

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("user")
public class IndexController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateStatusIndividually(@ModelAttribute("user") User user,
@ModelAttribute("e") String data,
BindingResult bindingResult,
Model model
) throws Exception {

        logger.info("IndexController - updateStatus() - Started");
    
    
    
    
        logger.info("IndexController - updateStatus() - Ended");
    
        return "update-end"; //redirect to update-end.html
    
    }

}
```

I need to gets the data to my controller so that I can do some kind of operation, the Project Development Plan=[Proposed, draft] unable mapped to controller.